# ARM function not returning properly

Tags: function, assembly, arm

I am stuck as to why this function repeatedly calls it self when it should return.

```
Initialize:
    stmfd sp!, {R0-R4,lr}
    mov R4, #0  @used for storing 0
    mov R0, #2
    mov R5, #0
    ldr R1, =sieve
    ldr R1, [R1]
    ldr R2, =primes
    ldr R2, [R2]
    str R4, [R1], #4    @intialize first and second elements in sieve to 0
    str R4, [R1]
    mov R4, #1  @used for storing 1
setToOne:
    str R4, [R1], #4
    add R0, R0, #1
    cmp R0, #MAX
    blt setToOne
    ldmfd sp!, {R0-R4,pc}   @For somereason Initialize repeats as if lr points back to its begining (instead of where it's called from)
```

Ok I can't post the entire program because it says "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

Comment: I can't see any reason why your function would repeatedly call itself, either.  How are you calling it?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on ldmfd and take a look at your stack?  (specifically the stacked LR).  Maybe it's getting smashed (where is sieve located relative to the stack, and how large is it?) - also assuming you are a "branch with link" instruction to call "Initialize" (which updates the LR at the time of the call) - otherwise your LR will be meaningless.

Comment: is your program trashing the stack?  What does the disassembly look like (with addresses, etc) and what does your memory map look like

Comment: @Dan the LR is 4100 the first time the break point is reached and 4108 all subsequent times. I'm calling it with bl Initialize. How do I know where the sieve is located relative to the stack? I'm declaring it as sieve:      .skip MAXLIST*4 where MAXLIST is 100. I guess that makes it 400 words (actually I'm not clear on how much space .skip actually skips)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `R5` without saving it first. I can´t see why it should make the function call itself, but it will probably give some kind of strange results.

As a side note, if you are calling this function from C, `R0-R3` do not need to be saved since they are scratch registers. If you are calling it from assembly, you can of course create your own calling convention which might make it necessary to save them.

Comment: Nope I tried saving R5 and that didn't make a difference. Thanks though.

Comment: Strange, that is the possible thing I can see that can go wrong. How is the function called? Can you debug and break and see what `lr` is set to when you enter the function?

Comment: 4100. **When I put the breakpoint at the stmfd the function returns properly**

Comment: Weird... Are you running it in an emulator or some kind of device?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a couple of different values of MAX and it's working fine:Initialize 
is returning to the instruction just after the one that called it (bl Initialize). Assuming you are doing everything correctly outside of this code snippet, the culprit seems to be your STR instructions. You are getting the value of sieve in R1 using the psedu ldr. sieve points to the memory chunk that got implicitly initialized as zero when you used .skip without the "fill". Now you are using `ldr R1, [R1]` which is loading zero in R1 and later you are doing a `str R4, [R1], #4` which is zeroing out the word at address ZERO. Now I don't know what logic you are trying to implement but if I go by your comment **@intialize first and second elements in sieve to 0** then your code isn't doing what you want it to do. Depending on how you are arranging your code in memory, you could be overwriting a portion of your own code with zeros. 
It could be that your Initialize is at zero memory address and you are overwriting the value of lr on the stack with zero. I am just taking wild guesses. Had you provided some information of the logic you are trying to implement and more of your code, then I might have been able to help you better. One thing you can try with is that once you have done `ldr R1, =sieve`, keep R1 aside for your STRs and use some other register in your `ldr R1, [R1]` like `ldr R6, [R1]` instead. Depending on how you are using R6 in the caller code, you might or might not be required to **PUSH R6** on the stack. This is not an exact answer, I wanted to put this in comments section but I don't have enough privileges to do so.